# How to show child column record detail on click master table clumn data retrieved from sql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I wnat to write php code which show master table data with join query to child in php and in php result data as we click on column data, it should redirect to child record detail. Example

Master table

```html
<table>
<tr><td>Id</td><td>Parent Name</td><td>Address</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>Ashish</td><td>1</td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td>Ankur</td><td>2</td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td>Vijay</td><td>3</td></tr>
</table>
```

Child Table

```html
   <table>
    <tr><td>Id</td><td>Address</td><td>detail</td></tr>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>Rajasthan</td><td>asd1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td><td>Delhi</td><td>2asdasdsad</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td>Jaipur</td><td>3sadas</td></tr>
    </table>
```

Non in php i wnat to show like

```
Name      address
Ashish    Rajasthan
Ankur     Delhi
Vijay     Jaipur
```

Ans as click on address link as delhi or jaipur it should open child record page and click on name it should open master table record page

Comment: Please show the PHP code that you tried to write.

Comment: $list = $this->db->query("select m.parent_name, c.address from master_table m left join child_table c on m.Address=c.Id")->result();
foreach($list as $data){
 echo '<div><span>'.$data->parent_name.'</span><span>'.$data->address.'</span></div>
}